# How do I save an entity for the first time that requires another pre-existing entity to be attached to it

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I need to save a Company entity to the database as a new entity.  In order to do this I need to associate a CompanyType entity to the Company entity.  I can't save the Company without do this.  Do I attach the newly created company to the context and then attach the company type entity to the company and then save my results?  This code works...but just doesn't feel right.

```
public RepositoryStatus SaveCompany(Company company, CompanyType companyType)
    {
        RepositoryStatus rs = new RepositoryStatus();
        try
        {
            using (RanchBuddyEntities dc = new Connection().GetContext())
            {
                if (company.CompanyID > 0)
                {
                    company.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
                    Company original = dc.CompanySet.Where(c => c.CompanyID == company.CompanyID).FirstOrDefault();
                    dc.ApplyPropertyChanges("CompanySet", company);
                    dc.Attach(companyType);
                    company.CompanyTypesReference.Attach(companyType);
                }
                else
                {
                    company.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                    company.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
                    dc.AddToCompanySet(company);
                    dc.Attach(companyType);
                    company.CompanyTypesReference.Value = companyType;
                }
                dc.SaveChanges();
            }
            rs.SetObject(company);
            rs.StatusType = Status.StatusTypes.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            rs.SetObject(company);
            rs.StatusType = Status.StatusTypes.Failure;
            rs.AddMessage(e.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.StackTrace);
        }

        return rs;
    }
```

The CompanyType was attached to another context and detached which is why it is passed in here.  Would I be better off passing in the CompanyTypeID and query for the associated object inside of the same using statement?

I can't stand that I have to take so many steps to get EF goign where LINQ to SQL was so easy!  Still - EF seems easier than NHibernate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
Company company = new Company();
company.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
company.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
company.CompanyType = companyType;
RanchBuddyEntities.AddToCompanies(company);
RanchBuddyEntities.SaveChanges();
```